# Can a ProxyHost be used on HostGator?

Tags: proxy, openlayers

I'm trying to setup a proxy host to be used with OpenLayers.

My hosting site is HostGator.

I've tried about 6 different PHP proxy scripts and none work.

They all return either a 403 or 500 error.

Is there something I don't know or do some hosting sites just not allow this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just asking: did you set allowedHosts variable in the script? Does your provider allow execute python scripts?

Comment: The proxy is written in PHP. Here is the exact one I'm using, with no changes made on my part. http://svn.codehaus.org/mapbuilder/trunk/mapbuilder/server/php/proxy.php

Comment: Do you know if I need to actually change something in the code for it to work? I have no experience with this.